# Node error TypeError: req.query.acct_stmt_id.map is not a function depending on array size

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await

I have a strange error, where the following route is working correctly for an input array of size 10, but throws the error `TypeError: req.query.acct_stmt_id.map is not a function` for an input array of size 100.

I am using `--max-http-header-size=65536` when running node.

```
// Edit: I am running node/express with these configs:
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }));

app.get("/api/v1/config", async function(req, res) {
  
  if (!validateAPIKey(req.query.api_key)){
    res.sendStatus(403);
  } else {

    if (req.query.arr_data) {

      try {
        // turn strings into numbers
        var input_arr_numbers= req.query.arr_data.map(Number);

        const [data, fields] = await promisePool.query("SELECT field FROM table WHERE status_id=100 AND id IN (?);", [input_arr_numbers]);

        if (data.length > 0)
        {
          console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
          res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(404);
        }

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);

      } 

    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }

  }

});
```

Update: I played around with the number of elements in the array and printed out the array in the node route. I noticed that up to 20 elements (`content-length: 475`) the array is actually a regular array, on which the `array.map()` function can be applied. With 21 elements (`content-legnth: 504`) it becomes an associative array. I have changed nothing on the sender side and when printing the request, there are no changes to what actually goes into node:

```
// I changed the array name (arr_data) vis-a-vis what I am really using in my code
/api/v1/config?api_key=ABCDEFG&arr_data[0]=657&arr_data[1]=637&arr_data[2]=567&arr_data[3]=517&arr_data[4]=587&arr_data[5]=627&arr_data[6]=607&arr_data[7]=557&arr_data[8]=677&arr_data[9]=507&arr_data[10]=687&arr_data[11]=547&arr_data[12]=647&arr_data[13]=537&arr_data[14]=527&arr_data[15]=707&arr_data[16]=577&arr_data[17]=597&arr_data[18]=617&arr_data[19]=667&arr_data[20]=697

// console.log(arr_data)
[
  '657', '637', '567', '517',
  '587', '627', '607', '557',
  '677', '507', '687', '547',
  '647', '537', '527', '707',
  '577', '597', '617', '667',
  '697'
]

// when I sent > 20 records in arr_data
/api/v1/config?api_key=ABCDEFG&arr_data[0]=1027&arr_data[1]=1047&arr_data[2]=1017&arr_data[3]=747&arr_data[4]=807&arr_data[5]=797&arr_data[6]=997&arr_data[7]=907&arr_data[8]=767&arr_data[9]=1067&arr_data[10]=717&arr_data[11]=1057&arr_data[12]=727&arr_data[13]=1007&arr_data[14]=777&arr_data[15]=737&arr_data[16]=1077&arr_data[17]=787&arr_data[18]=827&arr_data[19]=857&arr_data[20]=1037&arr_data[21]=757

// array.map(Number) fails on this (obviously)
{
  '0': '1027',
  '1': '1047',
  '2': '1017',
   ...
}
```

Does anyone know why Node/Express is changing the array and how to prevent it?

Comment: Can you add the values of `arr_data`? Also, are you sure it's an array when its length is more than 10? Also, check this link, it might be due to character length in the URL, just speculating.

Comment: I am running node with the ```--max-http-header-size=65536``` option as I frequently have to process large arrays in ```GET``` requests

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string#:~:text=Although%20officially%20there%20is%20no,a%20max%20of%202048%20characters.) link

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am using the API via a backend application using CURL so browser limitations don't matter here. Also I have configured the server to accept large headers/requests. Kindly take a look at my update above, node is changing the array in the get request to an associative array after a certain size, which seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by changing the GET request like so:

```
/api/v1/config?api_key=ABCDEFG&arr_data[]=1027&arr_data[]=1047&arr_data[]=1017&arr_data[]=747&arr_data[]=807&arr_data[]=797&arr_data[]=997&arr_data[]=907&arr_data[]=767&arr_data[]=1067&arr_data[]=717&arr_data[]=1057&arr_data[]=727&arr_data[]=1007&arr_data[]=777&arr_data[]=737&arr_data[]=1077&arr_data[]=787&arr_data[]=827&arr_data[]=857&arr_data[]=1037&arr_data[]=757
```